# AJAX receives empty string when the response is huge on MS edge\chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, microsoft-edge

I have a simple ajax POST request and the server sends data back to the ajax. It works fine as long as the response from the server is small but when the server sends a huge response then the ajax gets an empty string as a response data. The response status code is 200 OK so there is no error. This is happening on Microsoft Edge (121.0.2277.83) and Google Chrome (120.0.6099.225) but the same thing works just fine on Firefox. I can see that MS Edge and Chrome receive data (on the network tab) but the ajax shows an empty string.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //some code                        
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //error handling
    }
});
```

I tried adding "cache:false" to the ajax call but no change.

Does anyone know what is going on with the ajax on the Edge and Chrome?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `dataType` property or setting it to `dataType: "json"`?

Comment: Yes, I tried it and It throws a parse JSON error since the data, that ajax receives, is empty, in both cases.

Comment: You can try it on edge Beta or Canary version to see if issue persists. https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/edge/download/insider?form=MA13FJ

Comment: I tried both the Beta and Canary versions of MS Edge but same result. I can see it receives the data but ajax success call back gets an empty string.

Comment: I think this issue seems to be related to Chromium-based browsers, and I recommend you could report the issue here for more help. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: Yes, I think so too. I have opened a bug.